# Preencher um Array com dados Lidos de um Arquivo XML

Tags: php, array, xml

Preciso preencher um array com dados lidos de um arquivo XML, o código está listando todos do arquivo xml os dados no navegador corretamente:

```
if (file_exists('clientes.xml')) {
   $xml = simplexml_load_file('clientes.xml');

   foreach ($xml as $torcedor => $registro) {  
      foreach($registro->attributes() as $k => $valor) {
         echo $k." : ".$valor.' <br />';
      }
   }

} else {
    exit('Falha ao abrir clientes.xml.');
}
```

Porém se eu remover a linha do código `echo $k." : ".$valor.' <br />';` que lista os dados no navegador e coloco esse código `$novoArray[$k] = (string)$valor;` é preenchido somente o último registro do arquivo xml no novoArray. O resultado fica assim:

```
Array (
   [nome] => Dr. Samanta Renata Chaves
   [documento] => 834.881.326-84
   [cep] => 58136-468
   [endereco] => Travessa Pacheco, 0049
   [bairro] => Catarina do Sul
   [cidade] => Vila Amlia
   [uf] => BA
   [telefone] => (81) 2450-0382
   [email] => noeli.fidalgo@santiago.com
   [ativo] => 1
 )
```

Porém eu preciso preencher o novoArray com todos os dados do arquivo xml e sair no seguinte formato abaixo:

```
    Array (
        0 => Array (    
            [nome] => Dr. Samanta Renata Chaves
            [documento] => 834.881.326-84
            [cep] => 58136-468
            [endereco] => Travessa Pacheco, 0049
            [bairro] => Catarina do Sul
            [cidade] => Vila Amlia
            [uf] => BA
            [telefone] => (81) 2450-0382
            [email] => noeli.fidalgo@santiago.com
            [ativo] => 1
        ),
        1 => Array (    
            [nome] => Fulano Siclano da Silva
            [documento] => 834.456.850-02
            [cep] => 73050-468
            [endereco] => Travessa Pacheco, 0049
            [bairro] => Prazeres
            [cidade] => Brasília
            [uf] => DF
            [telefone] => (81) 2450-0382
            [email] => fulano@gmail.com
            [ativo] => 1
        )
    )
```

Alguém sabe como implementar essa solução?

Comment: Ja tentou $novoArray[] = (string)$valor; ?

Comment: Já sim, porém desta forma não atribui o nome para as chaves, fica um array gigante com as chaves numéricas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Teste isso:

```
if (file_exists('clientes.xml')) {
   $xml = simplexml_load_file('clientes.xml');

   $novoArray = []; // aqui estou criando um novo array
   $i = 0;          // iniciei um contador

   foreach ($xml as $torcedor => $registro) {
      foreach($registro->attributes() as $k => $valor) {
         $novoArray[$i][$k] = (string)$valor;   // a cada iteração do foreach pai
                                               // ele vai aumentar um indice 
      }

      $i++;         // incrementei um ao contador

   }

} else {
    exit('Falha ao abrir clientes.xml.');
}
```

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente José Veiga, muito obrigado pela ajuda!